# LinkedIn API: Retrieving a user's group memberships

Tags: linkedin-api

We are planning to integrate the LinkedIn login for users to be able to easily access restricted content on a large website.

While in general the integration approach is clear we are unable to find some specific documentation of the API capabilities.

Specifically we are interested to know whether it is possible to access a person's group memberships to be able to tie restricted access on our website to specific LinkedIn groups.

The idea is to give LinkedIn users of a certain group access to restricted pages on our website.

To achieve this we would:
- Authenticate the user using LinkedIn oAuth
- Retrieve the user's LinkedIn group memberships
- Allow access to certain content in case the user is member of the respective group

Is this possible?

Thanks for your help!